# Self-hosted video chat software

Tags: gratis, video-conferencing, self-hosted

I am looking for a free self-hosted alternative to Skype: a video chat server.

I have tried [OpenMeetings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMeetings), but it has too many features, I need something more simple.

I already looked at the Wikipedia article [Comparison of web conferencing software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_conferencing_software), but nothing free was good enough.

Comment: (Unless it works in the browser) For which operating system(s) does the client have to be available? Which OS on the server? Should users have to register on your server? Any other features? (Support for multi-user video chats? Text chat in addition? File transfers? Desktop sharing?) Does the server need any backend features, like logging, offline messages, user management, …?

Comment: The server OS is not relevant, it will be running on a virtual machine on which I can install whatever OS. The client would be better if it si a browser client, otherwise it should run on windows. All the other features are irrelevant, I don't care about registration neither about offline messages or chat.

Comment: Similar question from 2020: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/73912/1935

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [SignalRTC](http://signalrtc.com/), it's a video chat web application (no need to install anyting, no browser plugins), which uses WebRTC and SignalR, works only on Chrome and Firefox, not IE. I didn't check other browser.

No registration, user can enter any name. Now only two users can have video chat, but it's planned  multi-user video communication in future.

**Disclaimer:** I'm developer of this web app and now it's in development process, probably alpha version.

Comment: Seems interesting. Is the source code available?

Comment: no, it isn't open source. But application consists from 2 parts: server part is located on one server, and client part is just html file with JavaScript. This html file can be placed on any web server. You can get more info here: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/378959681/signalrtc

Comment: This really does not meet @user3161330's requirement of being self-hosted.

Comment: client part of application is actually self-hosted