# Is there a free and open source software for video conferencing?

Tags: open-source, video-conferencing

Is there a free and open source software for video conferencing that has end to end encryption?

I need it to support GNU/Linux, Windows, and Android smartphones.

Comment: There are plenty of video conferencing questions lately. There don't seem to be many options. With HTTPS, this might come close: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/73942/1935

Comment: Several. Jitsi Meet (as by the linked answer), BigBlueButton, Nextcloud Talk… At least Jitsi Meet and Nextcloud Talk offer E2E in 1:1 "conferences" AFAIK. E2E in groups is not that easy to achieve (everyone would need everybody else's key, and the steam must be encrypted for all keys – so at least hardware requirements would be higher).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Jitsi]

Quoting from FAQ:

> #### What is Jitsi?
>
> Jitsi is a set of open-source projects that allows you to easily build and deploy **secure videoconferencing solution**s. We are best known for our Jitsi Meet video conferencing platform, meet.jit.si where we host a Jitsi Meet instance that the community can use for totally free video conferences , and the Jitsi Videobridge that powers all of our multi-party video capabilities.
>
> #### What are the features of Jitsi Meet?
>
> Jitsi Meet includes many features and we are constantly adding more. Some of the main ones are:
>
> - Auto-view the active speaker or click on any attendee to see their video
> - Android and iOS apps
> - Text chatting (web only)
> - Lock a room with a password
> - Screen sharing (if jidesha is setup, only required in Chrome)
> - Streaming a conference to YouTube live (if Jibri is configured)
> - Shared text document based on Etherpad
> - Raise/Lower your hand for attention
> - Participant talk-time statistics
> - Push-to-talk mode
> - Play a YouTube video to all attendees call
> - Audio-only option
> - Telephone dial-in to a conference (if Jigasi is setup)
> - Dial-out to a telephone participant (if Jigasi is setup)
> - Integration in other apps / websites
>
> Jitsi Meet also includes statistics and integrations features and a callstats.io integration to help developers. Make sure to use meet.jit.si to see the latest features.

Also see the Question: [**Are my meetings encrypted? Is encryption end-to-end?**](https://jitsi.org/security/)

> Jitsi meetings can operate in 2 ways: peer-to-peer (P2P) or via the Jitsi Videobridge (JVB). This is transparent to the user. P2P mode is only used for 1-to-1 meetings. In this case, audio and video are encrypted using DTLS-SRTP all the way from the sender to the receiver, even if they traverse network components like TURN servers.
>
> In the case of multiparty meetings all audio and video traffic is still encrypted on the network (again, using DTLS-SRTP). Packets are decrypted while traversing Jitsi Videobridge; however they are never stored to any persistent storage and only live in memory while being routed to other participants in the meeting.

Link to get/[download](https://jitsi.org/downloads/):

- [Web online Meet](https://meet.jit.si/)
- Android Application: [on F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.jitsi.meet/), [on Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jitsi.meet)
- Apple App: [on Apple store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jitsi-meet/id1165103905)
- Desktop : [Debian](https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/debian/) GNU/Linux, [RPM](https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/rpm/), [Arch](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jitsi/), [Windows](https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/windows/jitsi-latest-x64.exe), [Mac OS](https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/macosx/jitsi-latest.dmg)
- [Source Code](https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/src)

Answer (score 0):

[ezTalks Cloud Meeting](https://www.eztalks.com/)

Features:

1. The ezTalks software provides free software hosting up to 100 participants.
2. The software incorporates HD video and audio, an innovative whiteboard and cross- 
    platform chatting system.
3. It supports playback, recording, and scheduling features to allow the users to share 
   video and audio recordings and send them reminders about upcoming meetings or webinars.
4. An unlimited number of live webinars, multiple presenters, webinar cloud storage, custom registration page and screen sharing with co-annotation are some additional features the software supports.

Comment: While it is free of cost, is it distributed under a free license (i.e. open source)?